# trycatch block not sent error when error triggers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, try-catch

iam using `react-redux` here and when i use `trycatch` block it not triggers error when error is executed.why??

```
    import {
      LOGIN_REQUEST,
      LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      LOGIN_FAIL,
      CLEAR_ERRORS,
    } from "../constants/userConstant";
    impo

rt axios from "axios";
export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_REQUEST });
    const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } };
    const { data } = await axios.post(
      `/api/v1/login`,
      { email, password },
      config
    );
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: data.user });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAIL, payload: error.response.data.message });
  }
};
//Clearing errors
export const clearErrors = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: CLEAR_ERRORS });
};
```

=>It was showing `LOGIN_FAIL` in `react-redux-devtools` but it was not throwing an error

Comment: try to console.log the error and see if it prints the error to console

Comment: yes bro, it was printing in console

Comment: did you console.log the error.response.data.message or directly error

Comment: direct error came

Comment: try to console.log(error.response.data.message)  and check if the error prints out to console if not then i think i know where the error is

Answer (score 0):

```
catch (error) {
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN_FAIL, payload: error.response.data.message });  
  
  // Log your error in the console
  console.log(error);
  
  // throw error
  throw error
}
```

If you want to console error or throw error do it this way but you actually just call your dispatch for the moment.

The try catch blocks are here to handle every situations your function meet, when an error come it's been caught but YOU have to decide how to handle this error.